# How can I implement Matrix multiplication with BigInteger?

Tags: java, matrix, biginteger

I'm trying to implement the matrix multiplication algorithm, but I have an issue dealing with `BigInteger`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Size of Matrix A");
   int tamA1 = scan.nextInt();
   int tamA2 = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Size of Matrix B");
   int tamB1 = scan.nextInt();
   int tamB2 = scan.nextInt();

   BigInteger[][] A = new BigInteger[tamA1][tamA2];
   BigInteger[][] B = new BigInteger[tamB1] [tamB2];
   BigInteger[][] C = new BigInteger[A.length][B[0].length];



    System.out.println("Values of Matrix A");
    for (int i = 0; i < tamA1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tamA2; j++) {
            A[i][j] = scan.nextBigInteger();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Values of Matrix B");
    for (int i = 0; i < tamB1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tamB2; j++) {
            B[i][j] = scan.nextBigInteger();
        }
    }


   if (A[0].length == B.length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < B[0].length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < A[0].length; k++) {
                C[i][j] =C[i][j].add(A[i][k].multiply(B[k][j])); // Result
            }
        }
    }

   }

    System.out.println(" C is equal to: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < B.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(C[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }


   }
```

Take a look at this output:

```
Matrix A
2 2
Matrix B
2 2
Values of A
2 2
1 0
Values of B
3 4
5 6
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at matrixmultiplication.MatrixMultiplication.main(MatrixMultiplication.java:56)
C:\Users\Luis Miguel\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

I don't know why I can do this operation with `int` and not with `BigInteger`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to SO, please add question in English it will help SO member to understand question or you can post your question here: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: if `A[0].length != B.length` the result matrix `c` will not be filled, but the last loop try to write its value anyway -> Null Pointer (add the loop to write into that `if` block and write a message in a new `else` to it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "difference" (or really a similarity, depending on how you think about it) between an array of `int` and an array of `BigInteger` is that when you make a new array of integers, all the integers exist (and are zero) while a new array of `BigInteger` is filled with `null`. Of course `add` cannot be called on `null`.

There are different fixes, for example you could fill the matrix `C` with zeros, or you could modify the multiplication so that it does not read from `C` at all but instead sums into a local variable which you initialize to zero.

Comment: I just add this piece of code:

for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < B[0].length; j++) {
                C[i][j]=BigInteger.ZERO;
            }
        }

Thanks!